# Is it possible to execute Javascript in the context of a page with Conductor Selenium framework?

Tags: selenium, conductor-framework

I am using Conductor to control PhantomJS via Selenium/Webdriver. PhantomJS has a function evaluateJavascript.

Is it possible to execute Javascript in the context of a page with Conductor? If so, how?

Comment: I have not tried it, but I came across a similar problem with HtmlUnit. I solved it by checking out the conductor framework GitHub project and I modified the Locomotive constructor to get the WebClient from the WebDriver. So you could try to cast the WebDriver to PhantomJSDriver and then access the internal methods like "executeScript", "executePhantomJS" and so on. Just an idea.

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much.

Comment: Cool ! I'll put this as an aswer then :)

Comment: Have you made any other changes to Conductor?

Comment: I have updated the used selenium Version, but had to revert it back because of HtmlUnit if I remember correctly. But I have not checked in my changes to GitHub, it was juste a local fork for testing purposes. I also wanted to prevent the browser from closing automatically after a test.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried it, but I came across a similar problem with HtmlUnit.

I solved it by checking out the conductor framework GitHub project and I modified the Locomotive constructor to get the WebClient from the WebDriver. So you could try to cast the WebDriver to PhantomJSDriver and then access the internal methods like "executeScript", "executePhantomJS":

```
 case PHANTOMJS:
        capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
        if (isLocal)
          try {
            driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);

            // Cast to PhantomJSDriver
            ((PhantomJSDriver)driver).executeScript(...)

          }
```